# javascript object data aggregation

Tags: javascript, object

I have a javascript object example as below:

```
0: {area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", 2021-27: 5.3670104041}
1: {area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", 2021-27: 0}
2: {area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", 2021-27: 0.1858817617}
3: {area: "F15 CMP", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-27: 0}
4: {area: "F15 GENERAL", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", 2021-27: 0.0326702424}
5: {area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", 2021-25: 0}
6: {area: "F15 DIFFUSION", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-26: 1.544808954}
7: {area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", 2021-24: 0.0270019481}
8: {area: "F15 PHOTO", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-24: 0.0001341795}
9: {area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", 2021-24: 0}
10: {area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", 2021-24: 0.3487656399}...
```

Each of the data pieces has 3 parameters. Now because the 3rd parameter date is different and I want to aggregate different date: value' into the same data piece together according to the same 'area' and 'dissection_name' value like:

```
0: {area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS",2021-24: 0.0001341795,2021-25: 0.0001341795,2021-26: 0.0001341795 2021-27: 5.3670104041...}
1: {area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME",2021-24: 0.0001341795,2021-25: 0.0001341795,2021-26: 0.0001341795 2021-27: 5.3670104041...}
2: {area: "F15 IMPLANT", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS",2021-24: 0.0001341795,2021-25: 0.0001341795,2021-26: 0.0001341795 2021-27: 5.3670104041...}....
```

So that for each identical 'area' and 'dissection_name', the data piece contains params for all dates as above. Is there a way to achieve that?
Any coding details provided will be appreciated.

Comment: So where is your JS code? what have you tried?

Comment: 2021-27 is not a valid property name, perhaps you meant "2021-27"?

Comment: @Simon Please check my solution, if that is what you are looking for, please approve the answer and close this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Array.reduce`

```js
const input = [
    { area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", '2021-27': 5.3670104041 },
    { area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", '2021-28': 5.3670104041 },
    { area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", '2021-27': 0 },
    { area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", '2021-27': 0.1858817617 },
    { area: "F15 CMP", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", '2021-27': 0 },
    { area: "F15 GENERAL", dissection_name: "WAIT_OTHERS", '2021-27': 0.0326702424 },
    { area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", '2021-25': 0 },
    { area: "F15 DIFFUSION", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", '2021-26': 1.544808954 },
    { area: "F15 METROLOGY", dissection_name: "WAIT_FOR_START_RUNNING", '2021-24': 0.0270019481 },
    { area: "F15 PHOTO", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", '2021-24': 0.0001341795 },
    { area: "F15 DRY ETCH", dissection_name: "DELIVERY_TIME", '2021-24': 0 },
    { area: "F15 WET PROCESS", dissection_name: "BATCH_WAIT_TIME", ' 2021-24': 0.3487656399 },
];
const output = input.reduce((acc, curr)=> {
    var matchingNode = acc.find((node) => node.area === curr.area && node.dissection_name === curr.dissection_name);
    if (matchingNode) {
        const matchingIndex = acc.findIndex((node) => node.area === curr.area && node.dissection_name === curr.dissection_name);
        matchingNode = {...matchingNode, ...curr};
        acc[matchingIndex] = matchingNode;
    } else {
        const newNode = { ...matchingNode, ...curr };
        acc.push(newNode);
    }
    return acc;
}, []);
console.log(output);
```